# How to set a dialog for portrait only?

Tags: android, dialog, orientation, portrait

Is there a way to showing a dialog always in portrait? I need that because of its layout.

I know that I can set that for an Activity with

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait|reversePortrait"
```

But what about a dialog?

Answer (score 2):

At the time of the dialog showing, check the device's orientation.

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
int orientation = display.getOrientation();
//if orientation is portrait then show, if not then don't.
```

Comment: Thanks @hwrdprksn, but I think the user would not understand why the dialog is not showing in landscape. In that case I'd better implement two different layouts - what I wanted to prevent.

Comment: Well that's how you tell which orientation your device is in. You can choose what you want the application to do after that. But I think this answers your original question, no?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure these ways will fit your requirement ,

One way is showing Activity as a dialog with screen orientation set to portrait (with dialog theme)
refer `DialogActivity` from `ApiDemos`

Other way is forcing activity to change its orientation by

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

and open dialog in `onConfigurationChanged()` (with some logic).